# Accessing redux store / functions from Navigation.js inside a tabBar

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native-ios

I'm struggling a bit accessing some redux functions from Navigation.js. I want to be able to call a redux function when I press a tab on a tabBar. To do this, I am calling

Navigation.js:

```
tabBarOnPress: () => {
 console.warn("I am here")
store.dispatch({ type: nameOfMyReduxFunction, })}
```

I correspondingly have, in a separate reducer / redux file:

```
export const nameOfMyReduxFunction = () => {
    console.warn("nameOfMyReduxFunction being called")
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: "NAME_OF_MY_REDUX_FUNCTION" });
    };
};
```

When I run the app, I get "I am here". However, the redux function appears to never run, as "nameOfMyReduxFunction being called" is never printed. Could anyone give me some tips on why this is?

Comment: You should either [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) the component or use [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) to dispatch the action. Do not use store in your components.

Comment: If your problem is solved, accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `connect` from `react-redux` package.

So first, we import the `nameOfMyReduxFunction` from that file and dispatch it from a function (which is named here as `mapDispatchToProps`).

While exporting the component we use the `connect` to connect the `mapDispatchToProps` function with the component like `export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Navigation.js)`.

You can call the `nameOfMyReduxFunction` within the component from `prop` like `props.nameOfMyReduxFunction`.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { nameOfMyReduxFunction } from 'thatReduxFile';
...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    nameOfMyReduxFunction: bindActionCreators(
      nameOfMyReduxFunction,
      dispatch
    ),
  };
};

...

tabBarOnPress: () => {
 console.warn("I am here")
 store.dispatch({ type: props.nameOfMyReduxFunction, })  //Access nameOfMyReduxFunction from props
}  

...

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Navigation.js)
```

For more info refer [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect), [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch). [`bindactioncreators`](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators)